# ExtJS4 MVC: How to select button by class

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs

If have a grid and I want to control (from controller) some buttons in tbar of this grid.

I can find button, that have itemId property, but **how to find button by class**, and what class need to use (there are baseCls, cls and other, they doesn't work)?

here is my controller code:

```
Ext.define("Wtb.controller.Schedule",{
extend:'Ext.app.Controller',

    refs:[{
        ref:'grid',
        selector:'button'
    }],
init: function () {

    this.control({
        'button#remove':{
            click:this.Remove
        },
        'button#refresh':{
            click: this.Load
        },
        'button#save':{ //Buttons with id works fine
            click:this.Save
        },
        'button.period':{ //It can't be found, because here is the class
            click:this.changePeriod
        }
    })
```

And here is button snippet:

```
{ //Button with ID
    xtype:"button",
    itemId:'refresh',
    text:"Refresh"
},'->',{ //Button with class. I need some buttons, like this.
    xtype:"button",
    text:"Period - day",
    cls:'period',
    value:'day'
}
```

**How to find buttons by class from controller?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the docs for ComponentQuery: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

This should get you the correct button:

```
'button[cls=period]'
```

Comment: cls property is not working. I took componentCls and using it.